# Filter an excel range based on multiple dynamic filter conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to filter a dataset considering several filter condition that can change dynamically based on a list of possible values. I have filter criteria **team** which have the following values: `Team A`, `Team B`, `ALL`, where ALL is a wildcard representing all teams. For the second criteria **release**, in case I want to include more than one release in the filter, the values are separated by comma, for example: Release: `A`, `B`, `A,B`, where the last one means to include both release A and B. I was able to make it works except for the case when the release value is `A,B`.

I think I should use: `TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(B4,", "))` to obtain in a column the list of values and then in some how (maybe using `MMULT`) to be able to add the filter condition per each row, but I was not able to do it (in Excel, because using Google Spreadsheet I was able to do it using a query function)

The following formula for single release value works for both criteria:

```
FILTER(D3:H8, (IF(B3="ALL", D3:D8<>"*",D3:D8=B3)) * (E3:E8=B4))
```

but it doesn't work for the general case where release values are more than one.

I am looking for a solution that would not require a VBA script

Here is the sample file:
[image: Dynamic Filter Sample]

Here is a link to the sample excel file:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7IhyhTnBFbln1G8fOj?e=C8OUxn

Comment: use ISNUMBER(MATCH()) on the TEXTSPLIT array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the idea suggested by: @scottCraner, this would be the solution for the release condition:

```
ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3:E9,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(B5,", ")),0))
```

so the entire formula will look like:

```
=FILTER(D3:H9, (IF(B3="ALL", D3:D9<>"*",D3:D9=B3)) * 
   (ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3:E9,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(B4,", ")),0))))
```

**Note**: it works also removing the `TRANSPOSE` function, i.e.:

```
=FILTER(D3:H9, (IF(B3="ALL", D3:D9<>"*",D3:D9=B3)) * 
   (ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3:E9,TEXTSPLIT(B4,", "),0))))
```

Here is the sample solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
=FILTER(D3:H9, (IF(B3="ALL", D3:D9<>"*",D3:D9=B3)) * (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E3:E9,FILTERXML("<c><e>"&SUBSTITUTE(B4,", ","</e><e>")&"</e></c>","//e"),0))))
```

[image: screenshot illustrating propo]
(if you decide to have multiple releases delimited by a comma without the space then the `SUBSTITUTE()` function will require to be updated accordingly)

Comment: Your solution works, thanks, but I think @ScottCraner suggestion is simpler one and more generic. According to [FilterXML function description](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7), it has some limitations. I created an answer based on his suggestion. Following the steps from your solution I was able to adapt it.