# Filter an excel range based on multiple dynamic filter conditions (with column values delimited)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I posted a similar question: [Filter an excel range based on multiple dynamic filter conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492445/filter-an-excel-range-based-on-multiple-dynamic-filter-conditions). Now I am considering a more general case, i.e. for one of the filter column (Releases, column `E`) it may have several values delimited by comma. The expected result should filter by rows that have as release values: `A` or `B`, but the releases column can come with more than one value and for team filter by specific one or all of them (`ALL` wildcard).

Here is the sample (when we have a maximum of two values for releases column):

[image: Sample]

I was able to obtain the desired result based on filter conditions, but it requires helper columns (columns: `J,K,L`), via the formula in `N3`:

```
=FILTER(D3:H15, (IF(B3="ALL", D3:D15<>"*",D3:D15=B3)) * (L3:L15))
```

and column `L` does the magic to identify the rows with the wanted release values:

```
=LET(result, ISNUMBER(MATCH(J3:K15,TEXTSPLIT(B4,", "),0)), IF((FILTER(result, {1,0}) 
+ FILTER(result, {0,1}))>0, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I am looking for a solution that **wouldn't require helper columns** and also for the **general case where Release column can have more than two values**, for example: `A, C, G, F...` if that is possible.

Here a link to my sample file:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ihyyx8_AM5ylbZWaI?e=F3WUep

Note:

1. I cannot use `TEXTSPLIT`in a single invocation to obtain columns `J,K`, because when the text input argument is an array (range) there is no way to delimit by empty string, so `TEXTSPLIT(E3:E15,",")` doesn't return two columns (it works for a single cell, but not for a range), so I have to use `TEXTAFTER(E3:E15,",")` to obtain the information after the comma in column `K`

Comment: Why not `C, A` in your result list as it have `A`?

Comment: True @Harun24hr it should be part of it. I will review it. Thanks

Comment: I have corrected it @Harun24hr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try-

```
=FILTER(D3:H15,BYROW(E3:E15,
  LAMBDA(x,MAX(--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(x,",")),
  TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B4,", ")),0)))))
 * IF(B3="ALL",D3:D15<>"",D3:D15=B3))
```

[image: Solution that works even for the general case]

**Explanation of the solution to identify if release value is present:**

It uses [BYROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) function which processes each row by a [LAMBDA](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-lambda-function) function you define.

The formula: `TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B4,", ")`

Generates a column array with the values of `B4`, i.e.: `{A;B}`(semicolon represents a column array) in our case a 2x1 array. `TEXTSPLIT` spits a string by delimiter (`", "`).

The formula: `TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(x,", "))`

Generates an array column for a value represented by `x` split by the delimiter (`", "`) . For example if x is: `A` it will generate: `{A}` and for `A,C` the output will be: `{A;C}`, i.e 2x1 array.

The [XMATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) function with signature: `XMATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, 0)`

will return the index position of `lookup_array` when an exact match is found for `look_value`, otherwise `N/A`. If `lookup_value` is a column array, the `XMATCH` function is evaluated for each element of the array and return the result in a column array.

For `lookup_array`: `{A;B}` it will produce the following output, based on the following input values:

| Lookup_value | Result |
| --- | --- |
| {A} | {1} |
| {A;C} | {1;N/A} |
| {C;D} | {N/A;N/A} |
| {A;B} | {1;2} |
| {B;A} | {2;1} |
| {B;A;C} | {2;1;N/A} |
| {C} | {N/A} |

In our case:

```
XMATCH(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(x,", ")),TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B4,", ")),0)
```

will return for each releases value (`x`) (`{A}`, `{A;B}`, `{A;C}`, etc.) a column array of size of the number or elements of `x`, indicating the row position of `{A, B}` (if matches) or `N/A` (not found) for each element of `x`.

`ISNUMBER` converts the result to `TRUE` (if matches) or `FALSE` (for `N/A`). `--ISNUMBER(cell)` converts the result to `1` (match) or `0` (for `N/A`). Finally `MAX` function returns `1` if there is at least one match, otherwise `0`.

Because `BYROW` processes the `LAMBDA` function for each row, it returns `1` (at least one match) or `0` (no match) for each row of `E3:E15`.

```
=BYROW(E3:E15,LAMBDA(x,
MAX(--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(x,", ")),
TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B4,", ")),0)))))
```

which is what we need as a filter condition

[image: Partial result of BYROW function]

**Note:** You can use `MATCH` function instead of `XMATCH`, but keep in mind that for the third input argument the default behavior is different. The default value for `MATCH` is `1` (largest value that is less than or equal to `lookup_value`) and for `XMATCH` is `0` (exact match).

Comment: Thanks @Harun24r it works even for the general case, I changed the value: `C, D`  with `C, D, A` and it works

Comment: @DavidLeal Glad to know! If you found it working then please accept it (tick mark the answer).

Comment: I accepted your solution. I also documented your answer while I was trying to understand it. I learned a lot with your response. It is really a good technique for other similar excel problems.